# Setuptools : how to use the setup() function within a script (no setup specific command line argument)

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm writing a tool to automatically generate .egg files from python projects.
The tool basically discovers some properties to guess the setup options (such as version number etc).

Now I would like to call the `setup()` function, with the context `bdist_egg`.

I do as such :

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
    project_dir = _get_dir(sys.argv)
    os.chdir(project_dir)
    config = _guess_configuration(project_dir) # returns a dict

    sys.argv = ['', 'bdist_egg']
    setup(**config)
```

And then I can call my script

```
python make_egg.py /path/to/project
```

What I would like is to skip the `sys.argv = ['', 'bdist_egg']` part. Is there a way to have the setup command passed to the setup function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setup(script_args=['bdist_egg'], **config)`